# Happy Medium between Ubuntu and Cinnamon?

Tags: unity, gnome, customization, cinnamon

I am very new to Linux distros and have been tinkering around. I'm currently using Cinnamon after a few weeks on Ubuntu's Unity. I really like Unity and I'm not too fond of Cinnamon, but I like the customization Cinnamon offers, the only thing is the one feature I really like, the top panel acting as a menubar, is not in Cinnamon and apparently can't be.

It's a really petty reason to drop an OS, but I also prefer Unity's software store. I was wondering if there's a distro that has Unity's overall look and feel, but offers the customization that Cinnamon has?

Comment: Try xubuntu, kubuntu, lubuntu .... There are other desktop environments. Go with the one you like best.

Comment: That's easier said than done, I don't really want to fry my laptop and I'm beginning to run short and USB sticks, ha-ha!

Comment: You can install as many desktop environments as you wish. Other then cosmetic issues and multiple tools in your menus they will all work. Once you find what you like you can fresh install kubuntu or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely try out other desktop environments like the others are saying, but I highly recommend not passing judgment on Unity's customization options until you install both Ubuntu Tweak and Unity Tweak Tool and run them to see a myriad of ways in which you can customize Unity.

Websites for these:

http://ubuntu-tweak.com/downloads/
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/

Additionaly, consider installing and using optional Unity panel indicators as demonstrated in this How To Geek article:

http://www.howtogeek.com/118908/10-awesome-indicator-applets-for-ubuntus-unity-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched to [LXLE](http://lxle.net/) (a.k.a. LXDE Luxury Edition) and am really enjoying it.  It's fast and highly configurable.  Plus, it's got a great number (and variety) of packages pre-installed.  It's currently running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but you can easily upgrade to 14.04.1 LTS after installing by changing the software sources 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version' to 'For long-term support versions'.

Comment: Oh my gosh, this one looks very nice! Might have to take it for a whirl, thank you!

Comment: LXDE == lubuntu (fwiw)